# Preposition for "besuchen" with website

Tags: preposition

> Besuchen Sie uns ***_*__** www.abc.net.

What would be the preposition here? Is it "an" or "bei" or some others?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"auf" would be the choice here. You can find numerous examples by doing a web search for "auf www".

"an" does not fit. "bei" would have a meaning of "near" or "close to" in this context which would sound weird for a web address.

Edit:

As suggested in the comments, "unter" is also good in this case. There is a subtle difference though: "auf" refers to the site, "unter" to the address.

> Besuchen Sie uns auf (unserer Website) www.abc.net
>
> Besuchen Sie uns unter (unserer Adresse) www.abc.net

These work equally well for the given example. A welcome message on the other hand should refer to the site:

> Willkommen auf www.abc.net

Using "unter" would look weird in this case. You welcome people to your site, not your address.

Comment: I think I've heard once *unter*. Aber das klingt  vielleicht nach Telefonnummer.

Comment: would maybe be interesting to compare the amount of google results for the phrase ;)

Comment: *auf* und *unter* werden nahezu gleichhäufig verwendet.

Comment: I guess I'd say „Sie finden uns unter...“ and „Besuchen Sie uns auf...“.

Comment: Andreas you should add "unter" since it is also widely used and perfectly correct

Comment: Unter ist gängiger als auf, wenn es um Webseiten geht.

Answer (score 1):

The German verbal prefix *be-* is a hint that the verb is transitive. So the simplest construction would be:

> Besuchen Sie unsere Webseite.

*Besuchen Sie uns auf unserer Webseite* is another possibility, as already said  above.
In connection with *Seite* "auf" is used.

> Das steht im  Buch auf Seite 17.